# Facing issue with OpenCsv : Number of data fields does not match number of headers

Tags: spring-boot, opencsv

I am using OpenCSV 4.2 in a springboot project and trying to parse a CSV file with 1 data row.

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10,col11,col12,col13,col14,col15,col16,col17
"1234","VSHRT","TTRYE","PLRTY","1165","NOW","","Collection","store/WEZXB6Z2CC_1.jpg","500","ABC","false","0","[{""name"":""fdtty"",""id"":""242541"",""value"":10}]","400","ABC","dummycol"
```

No new line character after last data column.

This is my function which return Iterator for the data

```
public static <T> Iterator<T> csvToBeanIterator(String csv, Class<T> clazz) {
 CsvToBean cb = new CsvToBeanBuilder<>(new StringReader(csv))
                .withType(clazz)
                .withSeparator(",")
                .build();
        return cb.iterator();
}
```

I am getting error

```
Caused by: com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException: Number of data fields does not match number of headers.
    at com.opencsv.bean.HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy.verifyLineLength(HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy.java:105) ~[opencsv-4.2.jar:?]
    at com.opencsv.bean.AbstractMappingStrategy.populateNewBean(AbstractMappingStrategy.java:313) ~[opencsv-4.2.jar:?]
    at com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.processLine(ProcessCsvLine.java:116) ~[opencsv-4.2.jar:?]
    at com.opencsv.bean.concurrent.ProcessCsvLine.run(ProcessCsvLine.java:77) ~[opencsv-4.2.jar:?]
```

I have tried multiple posts available on the internet but no luck.

Could someone please point the issue here.

Comment: DId U tried with simpler data set? Does it works for half columns? one column?

Comment: Getting exact error. Actually in my case, I have more columns in CSV and I want to read few of them only. So how can we achieve this? How can we ignore unmapped columns?

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced the same issue and I found that's due to the quotation mark  " in the middle of the text value.
ex: "Pulling Force Calculation for 16" OD376.5 X 12.5mm & OD 373 X 12.5mm(RDX)"
Removing or escaping it worked for me without any issue.

In your case, please check by removing or escaping those characters. Hope it'll work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and deleting some of the columns sorted it for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).